# How to show/hide windows using pyimgui

Tags: python

**Question**: 
How do I create **Something** that can either ENABLE og DISABLE a function, in this case, this function is called "imgui.show_test_window".

**Issue**:

> File "C:/Users/myusername/Documents/GitHub/UtilTracker/Main.py", line 34,
>   in draw
>       imgui.show_test_window() TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
>
> Line 34 = imgui.show_test_window()

**My Source**:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import cocos
from cocos.director import director

from pyglet import gl

from imgui.integrations.cocos2d import ImguiLayer
import imgui


class UtilTracker(ImguiLayer):
    is_event_handler = True

    def __init__(self):
        super(UtilTracker, self).__init__()
        self._text = "Input text here"

    def draw(self, *args, **kwargs):
        imgui.new_frame()
        x = 0
        xName = "Show"

        imgui.begin("UtilTracker",  True)
        if (imgui.button(xName)):
            if x == 0:
                x = 1
                xName = "Hide"
            else:
                x = 0
                xName = "Show"

        while(x == 1):
             imgui.show_test_window()
        else:
            imgui.show_test_window = None

        imgui.end()

        gl.glClearColor(1., 1., 1., 1)
        gl.glClear(gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

        imgui.render()


def main():
    director.init(width=800, height=600, resizable=True)

    util_layer = UtilTracker()
    main_scene = cocos.scene.Scene(util_layer)
    director.run(main_scene)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

In order to recreate this, you would need to install pyimgui, using the instructions on this link:
http://pyimgui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Is this spacing correct? I don't see any indentation after the `def`!

Comment: If you assigned `None` to `imgui.show_test_window`, of course it won't be callable. Please include the entire exception stack trace.

Comment: File "C:/Users/redfa/Documents/GitHub/UtilTracker/Main.py", line 34, in draw
    imgui.show_test_window()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

and I just accidentally f*cked up the spacing, my bad, it's correct in the IDE.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Please edit your question to provide a [mcve]

Comment: I have edited my post, it should be more readable and understandable now. Sorry for any misunderstandings.